# Is Clojure's "send" asynchronous?

Tags: clojure

I'm writing a simple networking framework for Clojure using Java's [new I/O package](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/package-summary.html).  It manages a pool of "selector agents", each of which holds a [Selector](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/package-summary.html).

I defined a `dispatch` action to for the selector agent.  This action blocks on a call to [`selector.select()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Selector.html#select%28%29).  When that returns, the selector agent iterates over the selected keys and performs I/O.  When I/O is completed, the selector agent send's itself the `dispatch` action using [`send-off`](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/send-off), effectively looping on calls to `selector.select()`.

When I want to add a new channel or change a channel's [interest ops](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SelectionKey.html#interestOps%28int%29), I send the selector agent the appropriate action and then unblock the selector (it's blocked on `select()`, remember?).  This ensures that `(send-off selector-agent dispatch)` in the selector agent is executed *after* `(send selector-agent add-channel channel)`.

---

I thought this would be bullet-proof since the call to `send-off` is performed before the selector waking up, and thus, before the selector agent send itself the `dispatch` action.  However, this yields inconsistent behavior.  Sometimes, the `dispatch` action occurs first and sometimes it doesn't.

My understanding is that it's not guaranteed that agents execute actions in the exact order they were sent when they come from multiple threads (i.e. `send` and `send-off` are not synchronous as far as queuing actions is concerned).

Is this correct?

Comment: If you want NIO networking within Clojure I'd usually recommend the excellent Aleph library (https://github.com/ztellman/aleph) rather than writing your own.... any reason you couldn't use this?

Comment: @mikera: finite state machines (FSMs) are a really good design for asynchronous servers.  I liked how easy it is to develop finite state machines with Clojure agents and was trying to figure out if I could use Clojure agents to implement networking protocols (specifically FTP which needs to manipulate two connections for a single client).  This wasn't for production development, it was an experiment with Clojure's agents :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`send` and `send-off` guarantee that actions will be placed on the Agent's queue in the order they are sent, within a single thread. Updating the Agent's queue happens synchronously.

I expect you have a simple race condition, although I can't identify it from the description.

Comment: The key part in that 1st sentence, I guess, is "withing a single thread".  I'm sending the agent actions from 1) the agent itself and; 2) another agent.  It's the ordering of these two sends that are problematic.  The `println` statements confirm that there is no race condition (the 2nd agent *always* sends first).  However, it turns out that there is a race condition at a higher-level for this update anyways.  Curses to mutable objects!

Answer (score 1):

You are absolutely right. Actions coming from the same thread will be executed in the same order, as they were submitted. But you cannot make any assumptions about execution order of actions, that come from different threads.

Comment: But that's exactly my point, they are *not* executed in the order they were submitted.

Answer (score 1):

send and send off are built for asynchronous state changes. 
if you need synchronous updates then atoms are likely your best tool.

since you need to preserve the order of requests you may have to use another data structure within a concurrency object (atom) can be syncrounoustly updated. It may work to put a persistent-queue inside an atom and have all your threads synchronousness add to that queue while your consumers synchronously pull entries from it.

here is the super brief decission chart:

- more than one and synchronous: use a ref
- asynchronous one: use an agent
- asynchronous more than one: agents within a dosync
- synchronous and only one: use an agent.

Comment: My question title is misleading.  I am using agents *because* I need asynchronous state changes.  My question is related to the *queuing of actions on agents* to be asynchronous: when `send` and `send-off` return, the action is not actually queued yet.

Comment: I'll look into a ref in the selection agent for "stuff to be updated before blocking again".  However, I'd rather have a synchronous `send`, since the agent itself already serves as an action backlog.

Comment: I implemented the queue solution.  Apart from being a huge by-pass of the entire agent system, it can't work.  The whole concept of relying on the "wakeup()" call just can't work.  I posted this issue on the Clojure mailing list for some extra help.  Thanks for replying!